# Upgrading SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2016 (how to handle SSIS,SSRS)

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

We are planning to upgrade our SQL Server 2104 to SQL Server 2016.

Our SQL Server is in a clustered setup, and infrastructure is planning to do a side-by-side upgrade (where they will spin up new windows server machines and move resources from old machines to new machines).

We have 99% SSIS packages stored in file system, and 2% in SSISDB (Integration Services Catalog).

We have SSRS reports too.

What should be our approach towards SSIS packages and SSRS reports, while SQL Server is getting upgraded.

- Should we copy the SSIS packages to Visual Studio, and change TargetServerVersion, and paste back to the folder location?
- Should we copy report server databases (2 of them) and database encryption key to new machine, and spin up new SSRS along with existing URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, the best is to add all the existing packages in one project and upgrade the project.
In the development studio for SQL Server 2016, this is really interesting feature that you can upgrade as well as downgrade existing projects.
[Project Properties Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlXbU.png)

Post upgrade tests your packages in lower environment, the only challenge could be any .net code tasks if used. sometimes code is not upgraded to the latest version.

For report server your strategy is fine.

- List item